# Android. Прочитать метаданные аудио

Tags: android

пытаюсь сделать что то вроде плеера. Играет. Но не могу никакую инфу о файле извлечь. На англ форуме есть примеры но с uri и классом MediaMetadataRetriever в которм не могу найти подходящий конструктор который принимает какой то медиа файл . Как мне прочитать инфу о аудио который проигрывается ? сам сервис который проигрывает у меня выглядит следующим образом.

```js
public class service extends Service{
    static String str;
    static int pos;
    MediaPlayer media = new MediaPlayer();
    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {return null;}
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        media = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.arena);
        metaRetriever.setDataSource(getPackageResourcePath());
        str =  metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_BITRATE);// никакую инфу не дает
        media.start();
        }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        media.stop();
        media=null;
        super.onDestroy();}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смею предположить, что в метод `setDataSource(String path)` Вы передаете не совсем то, что нужно. Попробуйте передать туда непосредственно путь до  медиа-файла.

[Пример](http://mrbool.com/how-to-extract-meta-data-from-media-file-in-android/28130)

**Upd**. Попробуйте вот так:

```
    Uri mediaPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.arena);
    metaRetriever.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), mediaPath);
    String artist =  metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
```

Comment: вот с путем у меня проблемы... не знаю как его задать. Файл находится в папке res/raw. но откуда вести этот путь - непонятно. Нашел пример типа - "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.arena ...но он что то тоже не работает

Comment: @PeteGr, добавил пример в ответ.

Comment: Да, заработало !!

Comment: @PeteGr, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).